# Building Apache on Mountain Lion libtool problems

Tags: apache, libtool, libtool-xcode

I'm trying to install apache from source on my mac. But keep running into problems. I've tried a ton of different things and just can't get this to build.

First, I couldn't configure without errors so I reinstalled apache apr. Now, I can configure but when I run make, I get this error:

```
libtool: compile: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: compile: specify a tag with `--tag'
```

I tried this to add in the libtool tag:

```
./configure LIBTOOL='/usr/local/bin/glibtool --tag=CC'
```

And this still gave the same error. I read that mountain lions glibtool is the unix-like libtool so that's why I tried this here. Still to no avail. I also tried symlinking the libtool that make uses to other versions on my machine, still to no avail, as I got the same error.

Here's what the make command runs, I tried `symlinking /usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool`

```
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 -std=gnu99   -O2 -arch x86_64   -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK  -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/X11/include  -I. -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/os/unix -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/include -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/aaa -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/cache -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/core -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/database -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/filters -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/ldap -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/loggers -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/lua -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/proxy -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/session -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/ssl -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/test -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/server -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/arch/unix -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/dav/main -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/generators -I/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.3/modules/mappers  -prefer-non-pic -static -c exports.c && touch exports.lo
```

This still didn't work.

Finally, I got further if I ran configure like this, `./configure --with-apr='/usr/local/src/apr/apr-config` (where I installed the system, but this is still broken.) This got me further but it still wouldn't finish make, and gave me a ton of errors like this.

```
exports.c:1809: error: redefinition of 'ap_hack_apr_version_string'
exports.c:1141: error: previous definition of 'ap_hack_apr_version_string' was here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out ...

For anyone having trouble installing apache on Mountain Lion, it looks like the default LIBTOOLS in the  source's build/config_vars.mk file is the wrong location.

I reinstalled LIBTOOLS with homebrew (which put it at /usr/local/bin/glibtool) and set this as the variable and all worked fine.